# Angular Testing Getting Actual HTTP Response

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-http, angular-test

I'm new to angular unit testing. What I want to do is getting actual results from my API. I checked [this](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests) documentation but as I understand, I should create mock responses. Here is my code,

**myService.ts:**

```
...

public GetAll = (apiname: string): Observable<Object> => {

return this._http.get("foo/" + apiname,{headers:this.options}); //this.options = newHttpHeaders({'ContentType':'application/json','Accept':'application/json'});
}
...
```

**myService.spec.ts:**

```
...

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
    ],
    providers: [
        MyService
    ]
    });  
});

afterEach(inject([HttpTestingController], (backend: HttpTestingController) => {
    backend.verify();
}));

it('GetAll() should work', () => {

    const testData = {id: "123"};

    service.GetAll("items").subscribe(data => { 
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('foo/items');
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

    req.flush(testData);
    httpTestingController.verify();
});
```

When I write the result in console, it writes 'testData' instead of 'data'. As I said before, I want to get actual result from my API, not mock result. Sorry if it is a silly question but how can I do that ? Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a working solution to get a real data**

**auth.service.te**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
interface Post {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getPost(postId: number): Observable<Post> {
    return this.http.get<Post>(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}`
    );
  }
}
```

**auth.service.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
interface Post {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}
describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
  });
  it('should get the data successfully', (done: DoneFn) => {
    service.getPost(1).subscribe((post: Post) => {
      console.log('data is ', post);
      expect(post.id).toEqual(1);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

[image]
Hope is helps

Answer (score 2):

notice that flush resolves the request , then you can use

```
service.GetAll(data).subscribe((response : HttpResponse<any>) => {
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);          
    expect(response.body).toEqual(testData);
});

const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('foo/items');
expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
req.flush(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: testData }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not mocking the service call, you can actually wait for the response. Since this is an async call, you will have to let the test runner framework know that you are waiting for the result. You can do that with providing a `done function`.

Sample code:

```js
it('GetAll() should work', (done) => {
    service.GetAll("items").subscribe(data => { 
        expect(data).toContain("something");
        //expect ...

        done();             // <= done fn invoked. This marks end of test case.
    });
});
```

More info: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/#_jasmines_code_done_code_function

Comment: When I do that, I'm getting an error like this: "Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL."

Comment: That means your http call wasn't responding in time or there was any error before the `done()` fn could have been called.